# how to check corrupted/bad files on kafka machines

Tags: apache-kafka

We want to check or verify the logs under `/var/kafka/kafka-logs/` in order to understand which files are corrupted or have missing info ... etc.

**kafka version - 10.0.2**

Is it possible to verify the logs by CLI or other approach?

The reason for my question is because we notice from `/var/log/kafka/server.log` a problem ( corrupted indexes ) with the indexes and timeindexes and we worry if the files are also part of the problem.

```
ls -ltr /var/kafka-kafka-logs

drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 16384 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.processed-1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 20480 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-95
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 16384 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-36
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 16384 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.processed-53
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 20480 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-44
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 20480 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.processed-17
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 20480 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-83
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 20480 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-15
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 16384 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.processed-66
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop  4096 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.tc.ppe_retry.gad-0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop  4096 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.tc.ppe_retry.wce-2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop  4096 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.tc.ppe_retry.wce-3
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop  4096 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.tc.ppe_mission.imei-4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop  4096 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.tc.initial.nce-4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop  4096 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.tc.ppe_update.wce-5
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop  4096 May 15 14:22 __consumer_offsets-14
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 16384 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-55
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 28672 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.mdr.initial-1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 16384 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.processed-79
drwxr-xr-x. 2 kafka hadoop 16384 May 15 14:22 kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-8
```

example under the topic - **kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-8** we have:

```
ls kuapi.jurg.pri.decoded-8
00000000000000000000.index  00000000000000000000.log  00000000000000000000.timeindex  00000000000000000008.index  00000000000000000008.log  00000000000000000008.timeindex
```

OR

```
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073738298 May  1 10:37 00000000000134399406.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073738600 May  1 20:36 00000000000135316397.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073739285 May  2 11:04 00000000000136250016.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073735132 May  2 21:53 00000000000137161280.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073740561 May  3 11:44 00000000000138080865.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073739395 May  4 02:53 00000000000138994373.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073741803 May  4 09:33 00000000000139934457.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073737793 May  4 20:57 00000000000140876452.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073727455 May  5 12:16 00000000000141818227.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop 1073741783 May  8 16:42 00000000000142754084.log
-rw-r--r--  1 kafka hadoop  471017673 May  8 19:32 00000000000143708830.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much you're going to get out of it, but you check the log segments and indexes using the [DumpLogSegments util](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-DumpLogSegment)

For example, this will spit out some output

```
kafka-run-class kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files 00000000000000000000.log
```

Comment: what in case we have hundred files under each topic partition ? , in this case we need to check each file separate ?

Comment: I not sure if it possible but we want some CLI or Tool that can tell us which are the logs ( we have millions of them ) that have a problem , so in that case we can delete it ,

Comment: You need to manually scan them, then. I'm not sure how you define "corrupt", but the server startup logs will fail to parse them, if they were.

Comment: Feel free to write your own utility off that one https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/fcf87816028830d168fd2142cf5277adcbade91b/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/DumpLogSegments.scala

Comment: BTW - do you have chance to look on my thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325194/kafka-what-is-the-meaning-of-invalidoffsetexception-in-server-log  , in this case we delete all index and timeindex and start the kafka broker , but we not sure it will solved the problem  ( the problem is that kafka broker fail on some index that corrupted )

Comment: if you want we can discuss on this problem in chat room ?